# When to use bucket sort effectively and how many buckets needed?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hello I wanted to implement a bucket sort. I think it works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>


void bucket_sort(int[], const int);

int main(){
    system("color 1f");

    int array[] = {
        5, 77, 99, 100, 77, 57, 23, 1, 2, 57,
            81, 24, 21
    };

    cout << "before sorting: " << endl;
    for(auto x : array)
        cout << x << ", ";
    cout << endl;

    bucket_sort(array, 13);

    cout << "after sorting: " << endl;
    for( auto x : array)
        cout << x << ", ";

    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}

void bucket_sort(int array[], const int size){
    int bucket = 10, divider;
    int min = array[0], max = array[0], j;

    for(auto i(0); i != size; ++i){
        if(min > array[i])
            min = array[i];
        if(max < array[i])
            max = array[i];
    }

    divider = (ceil( (double)(max + 1) / bucket) );
    std::vector<int>* vi = new vector<int>[bucket];

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        j = floor(array[i] / divider);
        vi[j].push_back(array[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < bucket; i++)
        std::sort(vi[i].begin(), vi[i].end());

    int k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < bucket; i++){
        for(int j(0); j < vi[i].size(); j++){
            array[k] = vi[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }

    delete[]vi;
}
```

The code works fine. But is this the way I should do? If I have an array with values close to each other but one or two are too much big:

```
66, 42, 70, 10, 30, 32, 28, 1000, 50000
```

How to apply this bucket sort algorithm? Also how many buckets should I use?

Comment: If one or two values are too large, then put those into a separate bucket. Sort the remainder of the array, and then add the big ones to the end.

Comment: @user3386109: could you add a good example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you get the number 10. You can use the total number of items in the array.

You can declare `vector` of `vector` to create a 2-D vector (instead of `new`)

```
vector<vector<int>> vec;
```

Ideally, `bucket_sort` should not rely on other sort methods. Here is a version which uses recursion. It keeps iterating until there is zero or one element in each bucket (or several elements with the same value)

Example:

```
void bucket_sort(std::vector<int> &src)
{
    if(src.size() <= 1)
        return;

    int min = *std::min_element(src.begin(), src.end());
    int max = *std::max_element(src.begin(), src.end());
    if(min == max)
        return;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    vec.resize(src.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)
    {
        //edit: double precision required 
        int v = int(double(src[i] - min) * src.size() / double(max - min + 1));
        vec[v].push_back(src[i]);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        //std::sort(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end());
        bucket_sort(vec[i]);

    int index = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        for(size_t j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++)
            src[index++] = vec[i][j];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> src = {66, 66, 42, 70, 10, 30, 32, 28, 1000, 50000 };
    for(auto x : src) cout << x << ", ";
    cout << endl;
    bucket_sort(src);
    for(auto x : src) cout << x << ", ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Testing:

```
int test()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    //add 1 million random numbers for testing
    std::vector<int> src;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        src.push_back(rand());
    bucket_sort(src);

    for(size_t i = 1; i < src.size(); i++)
        if(src[i - 1] > src[i])
        {
            cout << "fail\n";
            return 0;
        }
    cout << "success\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: changed division calculation to `double` precision, added test for 1 million

Comment: But all the values are put into `bucket 0` while only the last value `50000` is put in the last bucket `bucket8`?

Comment: Make up your own sort then

Comment: Thank you! One last thing: Could you advise me about this example?

Comment: I had a couple of errors in previous version, fixed it. The new version can use recursion and does not need `std::sort`. That takes care of the problem with large values, because the large value is separated in the first iteration. Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Yes I agree. I traced it; distributing values in buckets in a wise way. But is there a time cost using recursion here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Really interesting. In my real examples I use `std::sort` not caring about the implementation.

Comment: *"Recursion has no significant cost"* Why did I say such a stupid thing! Maybe I meant "recursion is not significantly slower" however recursion pushes everything in to stack memory, it can hit the stack limit before the first function call can exit and free the stack. This function isn't so bad but it can fail for large arrays, depending on stack limit (`std::sort` can sort billions of items) - A better option would have been to use recursion up to 2 or 3 levels, that would solve the problem with the `50000` which was getting its own bucket.

Comment: This particular recursion seems okay, because it goes down a limited number of recursions. It works for at least 1 million sorts.